# StackLINQ: A StackExchange LINQ Provider

Tags: library

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

```
var questions = from q in ctx.Questions
                where q.OwnerID == 34796
                select q;

var multiQuestion = from q in ctx.Questions
                    where q.QuestionIDList == new[] { 369558, 936804 }
                    select q;

var moderators = from u in ctx.Users
                 where u.Moderator == true && u.PageSize == 100 && u.Page == 5
                 select u;
```

### About

StackLINQ is a custom LINQ Provider that allows you to query the StackOverflow API directly using LINQ syntax.

**StackLINQ supports:**

- All of the API calls.
- Vectorized requests
- Proxy servers (via the Context)
- Total, Page, PageSize returned on the Context (where applicable)

**StackLINQ Apps:**

- [StackedDeck](https://stackapps.com/questions/1269/stackeddeck-watch-your-favorite-tags-tweetdeck-style): The TweetDeck of StackExchange
- [StackWatcher](https://stackapps.com/questions/1149/stackwatcher-watch-your-stackexchange-accounts):  The system tray app that notifies you of rep, favorites, and badge awards

**Coming soon:**

- Search API
- Take(), Skip() methods
- Complete test coverage

#### License

Released under the [MIT Open Source License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Download

The source is available on [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stacklinq).

#### Platform

Windows .NET applications

### Contact

StackLINQ was created by [Dave Swersky](http://www.daveswersky.com).  You can reach me at dave [at] daveswersky.com.  Please include "StackLINQ" in the subject line with any questions, and feel free to ask!

### Code

StackLINQ was written in C#. The source can be downloaded on [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stacklinq).

Comment: + i have been keeping an eye on this. i like where you are going. you don't know how relieved i was when you spoke up. i was not looking forward to breaking the ground on this.

Comment: dave, you might want to make a local temp clone to identify the missing files so that you can resolve them in your main repo so that the solution loads without difficulty. Apparently they are vestigal but the proj files are still referencing them. also, the modeling would be interesting to see.

Comment: @code: It's been quite a journey, LINQ Providers are opaque to say the least ;) I considered basing L2SO on your model, and did a quick spike to try it out, but I had gone too far in another direction.  I'll create a clone and clean up the references so the codebase works without issue on download.  As for modeling, you want a class diagram?

Comment: i was thinking more of the modeling project and sequence diagrams that are missing from the solution. nothing like hinting at something to get *some people* wanting it, but i understand scratch projects so no worry if they are not meant to be public.

Comment: @code: The modeling project is no more, the sequence diagram has been added to the main project.

Comment: @Dave - your download link has not been updated to http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stacklinq yet (and I'm still lacking appropriate edit rights by far ;)

Comment: @Steffen: Sorry about that, changed the name at your suggestion and forgot to update the links!  It should work now: http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stacklinq

Comment: @Dave - no worries, just realized it by chance and thought you could make it easier for new users easily ;)

Answer (score 6):

Quite impressive - am looking forward for more!

I'm afraid you'll need to change the library name soon though, as *LINQToStackOverflow* is at odds with the recently published [Trademark Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance), which explicitly asks for only ***one*** of the terms, "Stack" or "Exchange" or "Overflow" in your product name.

So may I suggest the obvious: **LINQ to Stack** ;)

Sounds pretty cool to me and I'd presume the term 'Stack' in itself ranking high SEO wise soon regarding the Stack Exchange sites, despite its generality, and even more so for developer oriented stuff like yours.

Comment: Interesting... I will work on a new name in that case, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I propose changing the name to StINQ or something equally clever.

Comment: Why not LinqOverflow