# StackWatcher: Watch Your StackExchange Accounts

Tags: app, c#, wpf, windows

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
[image]

### About

[Download StackWatcher](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stackwatcher/downloads)

StackWatcher is a notification area application that polls all your associated StackExchange accounts for activity, including:

- Reputation
- Favorite Changes
- Badge Awards

A "toaster" notification popup appears when activity is found.

**UPDATE:** A zip file has been added to the downloads section.  Unzip and run the .msi file to install.

#### License

Released under the [MIT Open Source License](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2kLg.jpg).

#### Download

The source is available on [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stackwatcher).

#### Platform

Windows

Based on [StackLINQ](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stacklinq)

### Contact

StackWatcher was created by Dave Swersky.  You can reach me at dave [at] daveswersky.com.  Please include "StackWatcher" in the subject line with any questions, and feel free to ask!

### Code

StackWatcher was written in C#.  The UI is Windows Presentation Foundation.

The source can be downloaded on [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stackwatcher).

Comment: @Dave looks pretty cool to me, waiting for a binary.

Comment: + I like the lib and that dave guy seems pretty happy so it must be good.

Comment: Don't forget to list this on StackList!

Comment: @system: there's now an installer zipped up and available on the downloads section at bitbucket.

Comment: @george: listed on StackList...

Comment: Cool, but I'm getting some exceptions: timeout and/or null reference.

Comment: @mgroves:  Does it stop polling after the error or keep going?  Are you behind a firewall?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not working on Windows (8x64)

Firstly, it doesn't not install in `C:\Program Files (x86)\StackWatcher` but the executable is found in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\StackWatcher.exe`

Then I wasn't able to set the the user up as it couldn't get the site list

[image]

I guess it's suffering from the same sort of error [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f/4730#4730) is