# StackedDeck: Watch Your Favorite Tags, TweetDeck-Style

Tags: app, c#, wpf, windows

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

[Download StackedDeck](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stackeddeck/downloads)

StackedDeck allows you to watch as questions with your favorite tags come streaming in.  Add as many columns as you like and StackedDeck will update automatically, once every 1, 2, or 3 minutes.

**Coming Soon:**

- Number of answers in question item
- Popup notifications

#### License

Released under the [MIT Open Source License.](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

[Download StackedDeck](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stackeddeck/downloads): Download the zip file, unzip and run StackedDeck.msi or Setup.exe.

[Download Source](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stackeddeck/overview)

#### Platform

Windows XP / Windows 7

Another [StackLINQ](http://bitbucket.org/dswersky/stacklinq) joint

### Contact

StackedDeck was created by [Dave Swersky](http://daveswersky.com).  You can reach me at dave [at] daveswersky.com.  Please include "StackedDeck" in the subject line with any questions, and feel free to ask!

### Code

StackedDeck was written in C# and Windows Presentation Foundation.  You can contribute by visiting the Bitbucket repository listed above.

Comment: Nicely done! I believe that Seesmic for Windows has a plug-in architecture, might be nice to integrate with that as well.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks!  I was not aware of the Seesmic plugin, I will definitely be looking into that.

Comment: I can't use this ... is there a tutorial?